# Python, loop trought in txt and print future login data

Tags: python, beginner

I would like my program to check what account I am currently logged in to (it works, I entered it (login4) in a variable for testing)

and when it reaches the end of txt I want it to go back to the beginning. It also saves the current position in case the program is closed.

my txt file:

```
login1:password1
login2:password2
login3:password3
login4:password4
login5:password5
```

and my code:

```
import pickle
import os

username = "login4"
nextline = 0
accs = []

if os.path.exists("conf.pkl") == True:
    with open('conf.pkl', 'rb') as f:
        nextline = pickle.load(f)
else:
    nextline = 0 
##First start program

##print(nextline)    
with open('logins.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if line.find(username) != -1:
            actualindex = lines.index(line)
            if actualindex != len(lines)-1:
                nextline = actualindex+1
                with open('conf.pkl', 'wb') as f:
                    pickle.dump(nextline, f)
            else:
                nextline = 0
                with open('conf.pkl', 'wb') as f:
                    pickle.dump(nextline, f)
            for logins in lines:
                login, password = logins.replace("\n", "").split(":")
                accs.append([login,password])
                    

print(accs[nextline][0], accs[nextline][1])
```

The code works as I would expect.
When it gets to login5, then it goes to login1.

**My Question:** Is everything written correctly or is it too complicated and could it be done more simply? I tried the best I can :)

Comment: Glad to see you over here!

Comment: @ThomasWeller I didn't know that such a page exists so I'm improving :D Nice to see you :)

Comment: BTW: do not accept answers immediately on this site. This site has much fewer users, so answers will come in at a much slower rate. Answers are also much longer, so it takes more time writing them. It's common to wait 3 days or longer.

Comment: Please do not edit the question, especially the code, after an answer has been posted. Changing the question may cause answer invalidation. Everyone needs to be able to see what the reviewer was referring to. [What to do after the question has been answered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). You can ask a follow up question with a link back to this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### What's fine?

It's great that you made a program that works. You have a level of understanding of the language and its libraries that allows you to solve problems.

For example, the usage of `with ... as ...:` is excellent.

Also, the use of variable names in plural and singular in `for line in lines:` is wonderful.

And, most recognizable: you are asking for feedback! This tells me that you are willing to learn. This is a good attitude.

Learning and improving needs time. Don't simply take the final output of this answer. Read everything and understand it. It's a long answer. (And maybe you see why such questions and answers don't fit on Stack Overflow).

### Improvements when first reading

Let me read the code from top to bottom (since it is not split in classes or functions) and tell you what I would change.

`accs = []` that name is not helpful when I first read the code.

`if os.path.exists("conf.pkl") == True:` the True check is redundant. `exists()` returns a boolean, which is true or false and you compare that boolean against `True` just to find out that it was true. This is called cargo cult programming. Simply write `if os.path.exists("conf.pkl"):`. See how that reads? If the file exists, then ...

`else: nextline = 0` and `##First start program`. These three lines do nothing. `nextline` is already 0.

`##print(nextline)`  was probably for debugging purposes. Remove it. Get familiar in using a debugger and don't do println-debugging like in the 1990s.

`if line.find(username) != -1:` This line checks whether `username` is part of the line. The pythonic way of expressing this would be `if username in line:`.

```py
actualindex = lines.index(line)
if actualindex != len(lines)-1:
    nextline = actualindex+1
    with open('conf.pkl', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(nextline, f)
else:
    nextline = 0
    with open('conf.pkl', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(nextline, f)
```

You have duplicate code here. Since the duplicate code is the last piece of code in each branch of the if-statement, you can simply write it after the branch and it will be executed in both cases, like so:

```py
actualindex = lines.index(line)
if actualindex != len(lines)-1:
    nextline = actualindex+1
else:
    nextline = 0
with open('conf.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(nextline, f)
```

Be careful with the variable name `f` for this file. You have already used `f` for the input file.

```py
with open('conf.pkl', 'wb') as configfile:
    pickle.dump(nextline, configfile)
```

Now, let's look at this code:

```py
actualindex = lines.index(line)
if actualindex != len(lines)-1:
    nextline = actualindex+1
else:
    nextline = 0
```

If you want numbers to wrap around and restart from 0, you can use the modulo function:

```py
nextline = (lines.index(line) + 1) % len(lines)
```

The part `logins.replace("\n", "")` is not needed. Since you read the file using `.readlines()`, there are no more line breaks in a single line.

Applying all these changes, we get this code:

```py
import pickle
import os

username = "login1"
nextline = 0
accs = []

if os.path.exists("conf.pkl"):
    with open('conf.pkl', 'rb') as f:
        nextline = pickle.load(f)

with open('logins.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if username in line:
            actualindex = lines.index(line) % len(lines)
            with open('conf.pkl', 'wb') as configfile:
                pickle.dump(nextline, configfile)
            for logins in lines:
                login, password = logins.split(":")
                accs.append([login, password])

print(accs[nextline][0], accs[nextline][1])
```

I hope you could follow all the points and how your program is shorter and has less quirks.

One thing I do not understand yet is why you assign `nextline` at the very beginning from the contents of `conf.pkl`. It will be overwritten in any case. I assume that your program "works", but I have the feeling that there's something else to it and it's not complete yet. Probably you want to get rid of the line `username = "login4"` in a next step. I'll ignore that for now.

### Restructuring on a higher level

With reading the code, I have now understood what it does and I can confirm that it works. Well done, and you probably get all points in an exam or so.  But, you want to become an even better programmer, right? So let's look at the code again.

A lot of code can be spilt into 3 pieces: 1. receiving input, 2. processing and 3. providing output. Your program is interleaving 1 and 2. Your program can benefit if we split that.

You are reading a file which has a defined structure. Reading such a file according its structure is called parsing. You are doing this here:

```py
with open('logins.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```

and several lines later here:

```py
            for logins in lines:
                login, password = logins.split(":")
                accs.append([login, password])
```

Do you see it? The first piece of code says: "the data is line-based". The second part says "the data is separated by colons". Let's move this closer together and fill `accs` earlier.

```py
with open('logins.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        login, password = line.split(":")
        accs.append([login, password])
```

Next, rename `login` to `username`, because `login` is more like the combination of both.

From this point on, the whole file has been read and `accs` contains the login data. We no longer need the file `f`. The login data has been parsed fully. We can put a checkmark on step 1, which was receiving input.

Let's rename `accs` to `logins`.

Now we're much better prepared for step 2, processing the data, because the have the data in a nice structure. Basically, the logic is the same, but we no longer work on `lines`, but on `logins` instead:

```py
for login in logins:
    if login[0] == username:
        nextline = (logins.index(login) + 1) % len(logins)
        with open('conf.pkl', 'wb') as configfile:
            pickle.dump(nextline, configfile)
```

Here's the complete program after this step:

```py
import pickle
import os

username = "login5"
nextline = 0
logins = []

# Ignored for a moment
if os.path.exists("conf.pkl"):
    with open('conf.pkl', 'rb') as f:
        nextline = pickle.load(f)

# Step 1: Input
with open('logins.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        username, password = line.split(":")
        logins.append([username, password])

# Step 2: Processing
for login in logins:
    if login[0] == username:
        nextline = (logins.index(login) + 1) % len(logins)
        with open('conf.pkl', 'wb') as configfile:
            pickle.dump(nextline, configfile)

# Step 3: Output
print(logins[nextline][0], logins[nextline][1])
```

Splitting the steps is a major move towards maintainability. Once you know that the input step is correct, you can make modifications to the processing step without breaking something of the input step. This was not the case before.

### Giving it more structure

There comments in the code above tell someone that you respected the input, processing, output principle. Let's do better and make these functions.

The first one is simple:

```py
def read_logins():
    logins = []
    with open('logins.txt', 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            username, password = line.split(":")
            logins.append([username, password])
    return logins
```

Note how the global variable `logins` moved into the function.

The second one is also simple, except for finding a name which honestly describes what the function does:

```py
def get_next_login_and_remember_the_line_in_the_config_file(logins, username):
    nextline = 0
    for login in logins:
        if login[0] == username:
            nextline = (logins.index(login) + 1) % len(logins)
            with open('conf.pkl', 'wb') as configfile:
                pickle.dump(nextline, configfile)
    return nextline
```

Again, notice how the global variable `nextline` moved into the function.

Since the output is just one line of code, I'll leave that for now.

Moving the code into functions breaks our code and we need to adapt for that:

```py
logins = read_logins()
nextline = get_next_login_and_remember_the_line_in_the_config_file(logins, username)
# Step 3: Output
print(logins[nextline][0], logins[nextline][1])
```

Now, let's create a typical Python main "method":

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    logins = read_logins()
    nextline = get_next_login_and_remember_the_line_in_the_config_file(logins, username)
    # Step 3: Output
    print(logins[nextline][0], logins[nextline][1])
```

Awesome. Your code now has some structure. Someone can decide whether or not to read a function. Typically, I skip over the functions first and look at the main "method", so see what the code does at a high level. In very short time I can now see:

1. it reads logins
2. it does something complicated to it
3. it provides the output

Getting this overview was not possible with the original code.

### Information hiding

Let's think again. The code in the main "method" prints the next username and password. Does it care about the line index? No. Should the output method know about the data structure and be aware that username is at index 0 and password is at index 1? Also not.

Hiding internal information is a common thing to do. It enables you changing your implementation without the need of someone else adapting to those changes later.

Let's fix this: instead of returning the index with`return nextline`, we return the username and password directly. "Give me the next username and next password" will be the API from now on.

```py
nextlogin = logins[nextline]
return nextlogin[0], nextlogin[1]
```

With this change, we can adapt the main "method" to

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    logins = read_logins()
    nextusername, nextpassword = get_next_login_and_remember_the_line_in_the_config_file(logins, username)
    print(nextusername, nextpassword)
```

### Final result

```py
import pickle
import os


def read_logins():
    logins = []
    with open('logins.txt', 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            username, password = line.split(":")
            logins.append([username, password])
    return logins


def get_next_login_and_remember_the_line_in_the_config_file(logins, username):
    nextline = 0
    for login in logins:
        if login[0] == username:
            nextline = (logins.index(login) + 1) % len(logins)
            with open('conf.pkl', 'wb') as configfile:
                pickle.dump(nextline, configfile)
    nextlogin = logins[nextline]
    return nextlogin[0], nextlogin[1]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Ignored for a moment
    if os.path.exists("conf.pkl"):
        with open('conf.pkl', 'rb') as f:
            nextline = pickle.load(f)

    logins = read_logins()
    username = "login5"
    nextusername, nextpassword = get_next_login_and_remember_the_line_in_the_config_file(logins, username)
    print(nextusername, nextpassword)
```

I still think there's something up with that `conf.pkl` file. Maybe you want to integrate that into the code so that it's actually used.

At the moment this unused feature makes the method name  `get_next_login_and_remember_the_line_in_the_config_file` so long and complicated.

Once you integrated that, you can then come back and ask for a code review again.

### Hacking it

I was a tester once in my life. And while you say "it works", I can also see how it doesn't work. It's a skill to switch between the developer view and the tester or hacker view. Once your program works, ask yourself: how would someone make it break and misuse it. Some thoughts for you:

- what happens if the file `logins.txt` does not exist?
- what happens, if the username or password contains a `:`?
- what happens if the password contains the username? Compare this in the your original version and the version we have now. Did we accidentally fix a bug while changing the code?

### Next up learning

As for the duplicate file `f`, a decent Python IDE, like [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/), would have told you. Use tools to your advantage and let your brain work less.

As mentioned before, I see indications of "println debugging". I imagine that it would be beneficial to you to learn [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Have a look into unit tests. Especially the `:` hacking case makes a nice unit test.

### Thanks

Thank you for providing the code and not being afraid of feedback. It may look like a lot - and yes, it is. This does not mean that you are stupid. I give this feedback not to discourage you or demotivate you. You don't need to do all this perfectly next time.

Pick those parts of the feedback that you understood. Integrate those into your next code. Ask for feedback again and improve again. Informatics has so many topics and so many technology that it's required to learn all life long.

Read your original code in 3 years and you'll probably say "this was horrible" - and at the same time, be happy that you write much better code then.

I finished my studies in 2003. And yet I'm a beginner on so many topics. I still get downvotes on Stack Overflow with 20 years of experience - just because something is new to me and I'm trying to understand. Do I care? Those downvotes mean nothing. I know that I'm on the right track, even when someone else thinks it's a stupid question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146750/discussion-between-jollyjoker-and-thomas-weller).

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer. I updated my topic with answers and new questions :)

Comment: My edited answer has been deleted;/ But thank you very much for your help. I need to create a new topic.

Answer (score 4):

Great review by @Thomas Weller.
Not much to add really, but I think you could have used the [CSV module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to read the logins file. It is a built-in module, therefore it is already available and there is no package to install.

This module can be useful to add a layer of abstraction, for example when the file has no **headers**. You can then process the file using a Dictreader and assign meaningful column names to manipulate the data with more confidence.

I find line.split slightly clumsy in this use case, because the delimiter is assumed to be known and constant. It's not like you need to parse some random text file where each line can have a specific format, that involves regular expressions etc.

But you still should expect and handle **exceptions**. A file may be missing, malformed, or cause permission issues.

Using readlines is convenient but keep in mind this will read the whole file and parse it into a list. You don't want to do that if the files are huge. It's wasteful, especially if you intend to stop reading the file and return once you've found a certain value or pattern.

Imagine you are completing an assignment as a **penetration tester** and you are writing a Python brute force tool that reads the [rockyou file](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/wjburns/common-password-list-rockyoutxt) (a huge password list). I would expect a difficult startup and serious performance issues with the current approach.

Instead you can just read the file line by line, and even read it using a **generator**. An example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38584783/6843158
In fact, I would recommend this approach, always. This is not going to hurt, even if the files are small. Thus you can have the convenience of readlines without consuming the whole file at once.

Now, I hope this is merely a hypothetical exercise and you're not going to develop an application that actually stores passwords in **plain text**. This is not acceptable in 2023. Hashing & salting should be done at a minimum, but there are libs for that. Even for a personal and simplistic project, I would avoid taking bad habits, and instead make state of the art the norm.

Answer (score 0):

Exceptionally I am going to add a second answer to better illustrate the implementation of my proposed changes.

There is still room for improvement in this application: we can make the function `read_logins` a bit more flexible so that it can be used with other files and a different delimiter. The filename and delimiter should not be **hardcoded** inside the function: we can provide them as **function arguments** instead.

This simple change immediately makes the function more **reusable**.

Since that function is a simple CSV file parser, we can even set the comma as default delimiter since that is often the norm for CSV, but that can be overridden.

Then, we can read the file using a **DictReader** and map the columns to **meaningful names** to facilitate the handling of column values. Because there is no header row, we provide the column names.

As previously mentioned, we can use a **generator** to consume the file line by line, rather than load the whole contents at once, which is wasteful. By doing this we make the application more robust and performance will remain constant regardless of file size.

There is still one thing I want to improve. `read_logins` returns list items, and the code that relies on this function therefore needs to be aware of **value order**. Username comes first, followed by password.

In the long run, we cannot guarantee that value order will remain stable, especially if you start using files in different formats. Relying on list index can easily cause bugs and breaking changes. We can get `read_logins` to behave in a more **predictable** and consistent way.

The trick is to use **namedtuple** instead of lists.
There is great background reading [here](https://realpython.com/python-namedtuple/) and of course reading the official Python docs is a must-do.

### New version

The revised function looks like this:

```
import csv

from collections import namedtuple


def read_logins(filename, delimiter=","):
    fields = ['user_name', 'password']
    Login = namedtuple("Login", fields)
    with open(filename, 'r', newline='') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames=fields, delimiter=delimiter)
        for row in reader:
            yield Login(row['user_name'], row['password'])
```

Usage:

```
for login in read_logins(filename='logins.txt', delimiter=":"):
    print(f"user_name: {login.user_name}, password: {login.password}")
```

So if you decide to change value order later, or add more fields, you will make changes to the mapping at one place: in that function. The code that depends on this particular function will continue to work as expected, because it does not rely on list index anymore.

I still don't like this version because there is **redundancy**. We repeat field names and it now becomes clear that `DictReader` becomes superfluous when we are already using `namedtuple`. It's time to refactor this code. We can simplify this further by looking at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields) for inspiration.

Based on the example from the docs our function can then be simplified:

```
def read_logins(filename, delimiter=","):
    fields = ['user_name', 'password']
    Login = namedtuple('Login', fields)
    for row in map(Login._make, csv.reader(open(filename, "r"), delimiter=delimiter)):
        yield row
```

As observed in comments, this version lacks the context manager so we can further improve as follows.

### Final version

```
def read_logins(filename, delimiter=","):
    fields = ['user_name', 'password']
    with open(filename, 'r', newline='') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=delimiter)
        Login = namedtuple("Login", fields)
        for row in map(Login._make, reader):
            yield row
```

This code is less forgiving than the previous implementation: a TypeError exception will be raised if the number of resulting columns does not match the namedtuple definition.

### Caveats

There is still no **error handling** here, so the function will misbehave if the file is malformed or the expected number of fields is different than expected. This should be relatively easy to solve. You can figure out this later if you need to handle files that were not generated by you. At the very least, it may be wise to skip empty lines.

### Bug

The original function does not strip the **line endings** ("\n"). The password values are therefore tainted. 'password1\n' is not the same as 'password1'.

Comment: Your final version at least leaks `open` handle. This is not critical (gc is a thing), but may become painful once.

Comment: Quite right, the example was for brevity purposes, but I made an edit to reflect your observation and improve code a bit.